# PHP error running script in include

Tags: php

I have a script in PHP that gives me an error:

Trying to get property of non-object in /home/include/common.php line 20

this is file common.php

```
    function Template($name, $type = -1) {
    // todo: default $name from the script name withouth the extension?
    $this->path = Template::getPath($name, $type);// this is the line 20

    // todo: verify the existance of the file
    // and throw the fatal error if not available
}
```

I am not so good in PHP and I am not sure if there is some php module missing in my php conf or another problem, any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: the script was working fine few days ago then my hosting company changed something on php and now it gives that error so I am not sure if there is some php module missing

Answer (score 0):

Is Template a class? If yes, should `function Template($name, $type = -1)` be the constructor?

Because if so, this isn't right for PHP.

In PHP you use (e.g.):

```
function __construct($name, $type = -1);
```

as a constructor.

Second, if you want to call a static method in the same class in PHP you do this by (e.g.):

```
self::getPath($name, $type);
```

I hope this solves your problem.

So you use `self::` for static calls and `$this->` for calls to the object.

If you need a Destruktor as well this would be `__destruct` (Methods with a __ in front are called "magic methods" and there are a lot of useful things you may want to look at ;-) ).

Comment: thanks for your help I was able to solve the problem

Comment: Glad you fixed it :-)